# how can i use the css ".not()" on a element and its children

Tags: css, css-selectors, children, pseudo-class

i have a [contact webpage](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/myself.html), in it i have a `div` with some `css` applied to that specific `div` using its `id`, i want to use this styling for more `div`s which i am going to add, but only direct descendants of `body`. however i have a header `div`, which i use on all my pages on this site, and i dont want this styling to apply to it, or its children.

how can i use the `css` `:not()` selector, on the `#header` `div` *and* on its children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS selector for all `DIV` elements except `#header`:

```
div:not(#header) { }
```

CSS selector for its children

```
div:not(#header) > * { }
```

or for all its descendants

```
div:not(#header) * { }
```

**Edit**

CSS selector for all `DIV` elements that are `body` childs except `div#header`

```
body > div:not(#header)
```

Comment: your answer messes up everything else on my page. http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/myself.html - see it yourself.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight well, you used `div:not(#header) *` so it applied to all descendants. Use `div:not(#header) > *` instead.

Comment: yes i did it, it works. i still dont understand why that had anything to do, whats the connection between `#header` descendants and all ot her elements?

Comment: descendants are all elements inside itself, but when you explicitly use `>` to select only its children the style rule will stop there (1st level) and it will not be applied to every element inside.

Comment: ummm... i noticed that the `css` isnt being applied to the `div` - its being applied to the children??? at least according to firebug.... and chrome developers tool... umm help?

Comment: its applied to the children but if you want to apply it also to the `div` just add the rule `div:not(#header)`. Something like `div:not(#header), div:not(#header) > * { }` will apply the rule to the `div` and its children.

Comment: no, no, no, no, i want all `div`s **only and not their children**, but i also dont want `#header` and *it's* children. i am very funcused atm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37238/discussion-between-letiagoalves-and-tryingtogetprogrammingstraight)